How to tell Git to use textconv for diffs but not for blame?
I have a repository with lots of 3rd party files located in subdirectory vendor and a few hundred files that I maintain. I have following .gitattributes file:
[attr]BINARY diff=binary -merge -text
vendor/** BINARY

with the "binary" textconf driver configured to list some stats about the file and take first 10K of the file and run strings on it. This works fine for diffing to get idea about changes to 3rd party files but it turns out that whenever I try to run git blame -C -C ... on any file outside the vendor directory, Git runs textconv driver against every file in the vendor directory while looking for matches which is obviously very slow process. (I was able to figure out that textconv is the problem by running GIT_TRACE=1 GIT_TRACE_PERFORMANCE=1 git blame -C -C ... and looking at the output.)
I know that I could add --no-textconv to git blame to turn off all textconv support for single invocation but I would want to automate this and possibly use textconv driver for other files which are not similarly problematic.
I would have expected something like
[attr]BINARY diff=binary blame= -merge -text
vendor/** BINARY

or
[attr]BINARY diff=binary -blame -merge -text
vendor/** BINARY

to work but it seems that git blame always uses the diff configuration instead. The best I can figure out is to use configuration
[attr]BINARY diff= -merge -text
vendor/** BINARY

which disables the merge driver for all BINARY files which causes the driver not being used for diff either, but avoids the huge performance penalty while I'm running git blame -C -C.
Does Git somehow support configuring textconv separately for git diff (and git log -p and similar) vs git blame?

I don't see --[no-]textconv in git help blame.

It's passed from git blame to git log internally so you have to look at the documentation of git log instead: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log/2.45.0#Documentation/git-log.txt---no-textconv or look at the internal test cases that Git project uses: https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/t/t8006-blame-textconv.sh

Interesting, thanks!
